# java in class.java in defining a new Intent does not recognize

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

I am writing an android program with kotlin.
I have a problem when I want to define new intent, java in class.java does not recognize

```
val intent = Intent(this,NormalBtActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found that I have to add this line in my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.21")
}
```

and the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your lines of code as below

```
val intent = Intent(youractivityname.this,NormalBtActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

if you are writing this in any listener, then you need to add below lines

```
val intent = Intent(this@youractivityname,NormalBtActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```